# MATLAB: How to count number frequency columnwise, in continuous blocks

Tags: matlab, matrix, frequency

I have a matrix `a` in Matlab that looks like the following:

```
a = zeros(10,3); 
a(3:6,1)=2; a(5:9,3)=1; a(5:7,2)=3; a(8:10,1)=2;

a =
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
 2     0     0
 2     0     0
 2     3     1
 2     3     1
 0     3     1
 2     0     1
 2     0     1
 2     0     0
```

I would like to obtain a cell array with the number of times that each number appears in a column. Also, it should be ordered depending on the element value, regardless of the column number. In the example above I would like to obtain the cell:

```
b = {[5],[4,3],[3]}
```

Because the number 1 appears once for 5 times, the number 2 twice in blocks of 4 and 3, and the number 3 once for 3 times. As you can see the recurrences are ordered according to the element value and not to the number of the column where the elements appear.

Comment: Will blocks always be separated by zeros?

Comment: Yes they will @LuisMendo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not concerned with the column, you can string all the columns into a single column vector, padding with zeroes on either end to prevent spans at the start and end of columns from running together:

```
v = reshape(padarray(a, [1 0]), [], 1);
% Or if you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox function padarray...
v = reshape([zeros(1, size(a, 2)); a; zeros(1, size(a, 2))], [], 1);
```

Now, assuming spans are always separated by 1 or more zeroes, you can find the length of each span as follows:

```
endPoints = find(diff(v) ~= 0);  % Find where transitions to or from 0 occur
spans = endPoints(2:2:end)-endPoints(1:2:end); % Index of transitions to 0 minus
                                               % index of transitions from 0
```

And finally you can [accumulate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) the spans based on the value present in those spans:

```
b = accumarray(v(endPoints(1:2:end)+1), spans, [], @(v) {v(:).'}).';
```

And for your example:

```
b =

  1×3 cell array

    [5]    [1×2 double]    [3]
```

### Note:

The ordering of values in the resulting cell array is not guaranteed to match the order in `spans` (i.e. `b{2}` above is `[3 4]` instead of `[4 3]`). If order matters, you'll need to sort your subscripts [as per this section of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#bt44joi-1). Here's how you would change the computation of `b`:

```
[vals, index] = sort(v(endPoints(1:2:end)+1));
b = accumarray(vals, spans(index), [], @(v) {v(:).'}).';
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer because it provides the solution slightly more quickly than the other provided by Peter. For very big arrays like mine it can make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

The hard part is finding and separating the blocks.  `diff` will find the starting point of any run of numbers, which is the starting point for this solution:

```
b = [zeros(1,size(a,2)); a; zeros(1,size(a,2))];
idx = diff(b)~=0;
block_values = b(idx);
block_lengths = diff([0; find(idx)]);
```

Now we have two vectors of the values of each block, and how long they are, and they just need to be captured in the cell array, ignoring the zero blocks

```
c = accumarray(block_values(block_values~=0), block_lengths(block_values~=0), [], @(x) {x}).';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = {}
for i = 1:ncolumns
    for n = 1:nnumbers
        b{i}(n) = sum(a(:,i) == n)
    end
end
```

(Note that this places zeros for numbers at which the count is 0, but otherwise I don't see how else you would be able to recognize which value is being counted)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would not mind about 0s, the problem is that in this way the total of the times a value appears is obtained (e.g. 7 for the value 2, when I would like to obtain 4,3). Also, the order in which the frequencies are counted is that of the column, not that of the value.